# Flex 4 spark Panel has an ugly gray top part

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, panel

I have a Flex 4 spark Panel I'm popping up through the PopUpManager, but it has a gray portion at the top I can't get rid of.  What is that and how can I remove it?

***UPDATE***: An example Panel is below.  I simply call `PopUpManager.addPopUp(new TestPanel(), background, true);` on it and receive that solid gray bar above the button.

```
<s:Panel xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
         xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
         dropShadowVisible="false"
         backgroundAlpha="0"
         controlBarVisible="false"
         borderVisible="false">
    <s:VGroup>
        <s:Button label="A button" width="150" height="55"/>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Panel>
```

Comment: Can you give us a code example or a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, this is how I did it.  I made a custom skin: HeaderlessPanelSkin.as

```
public class HeaderlessPanelSkin extends PanelSkin {
   public function HeaderlessPanelSkin() {
        super();

        topGroup.includeInLayout = false;
    }
}
```

Then, in the panel, I just reference the new skin: `skinClass="HeaderlessPanelSkin"`

That should do it :)

Comment: Perfect!  Why wouldn't adobe make this very easy?  Seems like a common enough need...

Comment: In the old Panel (`mx:Panel`), it WAS easy... `headerHeight`. Apparently, in the Spark implementation, they decided that you have a ton of control in skinning, and that keeping headerHeight would seem arbitrary... skinning is the way to go.  That being said, I hate writing an entirely new skin just to change a single property, which is why I like this subclassing approach.  Glad you like it :)

Comment: Why is the constructor of HeadlerlessPanelSkin() being overridden?

Comment: @Brian Bishop: Honestly, I don't know.  I am surprised it even compiles, actually.  Non-constructor functions can't do that... I wonder if it means anything...?  I grabbed the code from a different skin I had, which had that in it... I hand't noticed it.  *fixed*

Answer (score 3):

Create new skin, and in the panel declaration use it... like so

File->New MXML Skin, Host Component is panel.

Edit the Skin properties to change it how you like, in this case the gradient colors on the header.

Comment: Here's a good tutorial on this:http://www.popamihai.com/2010/11/flex/skinning-flex-4-components-skinning-the-spark-panel-component/

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the Panel TitleBar

Create a custom skin and style the title bar how you want it to appear.